# Google Map on Android

Tags: android, google-maps

We have an application that uses google maps' api.

After following the tutorial on how to generate a keystore, fingerprint and api key here: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html. We have successfully run our application with maps showing.

But after sometime the map stop showing, I tried to create a new key using the same procedure but didn't work. Finally I tried creating on a new machine and it worked. Is anyone have any idea what's causing this problem?

Comment: @Deepak just did that. @ernazm yes I was thinking about :-). But it seems my machine is blocked because even if I create a different keystore and api key it doesn't work :-?

Answer (score 2):

Did you know that Google has limitation on request to be processed? While you run your application, how many request (roughly) google maps should serve then? 
Please checkout [Google Maps API FAQ](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/faq.html#usagelimits)

Comment: Hi, yes I've already check the limits and looking at it again 2500/day which is impossible for me to reach because I'm only testing alone and I'm sure I didn't reach 2K not even 100.

Comment: Well, there's another option. Did you try your app with key on emulator or on real device? Alternatively, just pick another key.